# .editorconfig - will it allow easier git merging of two developers with different styles?

Tags: git, editorconfig

Me and my friend both develop an app. He likes one kind of coding style, I like a different one.

Now, sometimes when we merge and have conflicts, it's hard to merge, because the meaningful changes are obscured by lots of meaningless misplaced spaces.

I discovered an .editorconfig recently, but I don't get how is it gonna help me. Alright, I can see it will change the code in my editor according to my settings, but what exactly will it save to git? Will it have some kind of "default formatting" that is neither mine, nor my friend's formatting or what? I don't get it and I'd like to know before I commit to it.

For example, I like tabs, he likes 2 spaces. Which will be saved in git?

Thank you!

Comment: Could just try it and see :) TBH I'd try to find some common ground to avoid shenanigans, or use a known-quantity auto-formatter on commit (or run it locally). Re: spaces vs tabs... your friend is right ;)

Answer (score 0):

Whether (and if so, how) an editor configuration file can be used for this depends on how fancy that editor configuration is.

In general, this sort of thing is done by using a code reformatter.  For C and C++, there's `clang-format`; for Python, there is `black`; Go has had a standard formatter for a long time, and Rust has one now.

When and how to use one is a matter of opinion.  What Git will store in the *repository* is whatever you have Git put in its *index* before you run `git commit`.  The key here is to remember that Git makes commits from files stored in its index (aka "staging area"), not the files you see in your working tree.  So it's possible to keep your working tree formatted one way, and your index / staging-area formatted another way.

If you want to do this, you can consider using clean and smudge filters.  Whether and how well these work with any particular formatting tools you have will depend on the formatting tools you have.  The other main option is to do the work in a tree separate from Git's working tree.

If you choose to try to do this with clean and smudge filters, remember these items:

- A *clean filter* works during `git add`.  The file in your working tree, that `git add` sees, will be passed through the clean filter on the way to storing the data in Git's index, making it ready to be committed.
- A *smudge filter* works during `git checkout` and other operations that extract a file *from* the staging area to your working tree.  Here you'd take the as-stored-in-Git data and reformat it to the way you prefer to see it.

Note that it's wise to make sure that cleaning a clean file has no effect, and smudging a smudged file has no effect.  Git tries to do each operation only once, but accidents happen.